# Instalacion de gitlab en subdominio de subdominio (apache) en Debian

Tags: apache, git, nginx, debian, dominio

queria preguntar si para instalar gitlab lo puedo hacer desde un subdominio de un subdominio, es decir, estoy intentando instalar en un servidor de una universidad por lo que es un subdominio: ing.universidad.edu.co; por lo tanto la pregunta es si puedo especificarle a gitlab que sea accedido mediante gitlab.ing.universidad.edu.co.. Tendre que tocar los dns? o tengo que crear un subdominio aparte para este?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias empezar por darle una ojeada a una pregunta realizada en la comunidad en  Ingles [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012226/install-gitlab-on-subdomain)

Partiendo de este hecho, podemos hablar de algo llamado el *Proxy Reverso || Reverse Proxy*, el cual es usado en los servidores web, tales como apache o nginx para permitir que puedas *enmascarar* un puerto a traves de un puerto web (80,443).

Personalmente yo uso "gogs" este a diferencia de gitlab, es gratuito e ilimitado, y tambien sigue en desarrollo, tuve que configurar un ReverseProxy para poder accederlo con un subdominio, a continuacion te comparto la configuracion del sitio en `/etc/apache/sites-available/gogs`:

`

```
ServerName git.miservidor.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

```
SSLEngine ON

ServerName git.miservidor.com

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.pem

ProxyPreserveHost ON
ProxyRequests OFF

<Proxy *>
     Order allow,deny
 Allow From 190.0.0.1
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

`

En este caso, como puedes ver, en AllowFrom, indicas la direccion ip desde donde sera accesible el sitio (Si vas a guardar tu codigo, lo mejor es prevenir que llorar).

Y en la clausula ProxyPass y ProxyPassReverse, se indica nuestro host local (127.0.0.1) Y el puerto sobre el que corre nuestro servidor de git (en mi caso es gogs), con esto, es apache quien se encarga de atender las peticiones evitando exponer nuestro servidor de git directamente.

Espero te sirva